# Show minutes and seconds changing every second in ionic html page

Tags: typescript, ionic3, angular5

I have made a java-script countdown counter and displaying minutes and seconds using this line

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Number(this.minutes) + 'm' + Number(this.seconds) + 's ';
```

but in ios it showing me NANm NANs due to this line. So i want to use other way to show minutes and seconds.

Here is my typescript code.

```
 if ((this.Fajardistance <= '59') && (this.Fajardistance >= '0')) {

    let current_datetime = new Date()
    let formatted_date = current_datetime.getFullYear() + "-" + (current_datetime.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + current_datetime.getDate()
    console.log("formatted_date", formatted_date);

    // Set the date we're counting down to
    var countDownDate = new Date(`${formatted_date.toString()} ${value.fajar_iqamah}`).getTime();        
    console.log("countDownDate", countDownDate);

    // Update the count down every 1 second
    this.interavalTime = setInterval(function () {

      // Get todays date and time
      var now = new Date().getTime();

      // Find the distance between now and the count down date
      var distance = countDownDate - now;

      this.testing = false;
      // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
      this.minutes = Math.floor((Number(distance) % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      this.seconds = Math.floor((Number(distance) % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      //In these consoles minutes and seconds are as desired output just want to show them 
      console.log("Minutes:", this.minutes);
      console.log("Seconds:", this.seconds);

      //I was using this line to display minutes and seconds but it's incorrect way to display in ios devices.

      //document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Number(this.minutes) + 'm' + Number(this.seconds) + 's ';


      //  // If the count down is over, write some text 
      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(this.interavalTime);

        document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
      }
      //console.log("Inside notification function outside if");


    }, 1000);

  }
```

Home.Html

```
<!--<span mode="md" id="demo" style="text-align:right;font-size: 16px; display:inline-block;margin-left: 16px;  margin-top: 0px; color:red;"></span>-->
```

I was using above commented method earlier to display but it was not correct way for ios.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of issues with your code.

1. what is value.fajar_iqamah?
2. You are doing **countDownDate - now**. **now** will always be bigger than countDown, so your interval will run only once.
3. Even if you switch **countDownDate - now** with **now - countDownDate**, then distance will always be greater than 0, in fact it will keep increase rather than decreasing.

Comment: 1- it's the time in seconds 
2- No, it's not bigger. As i told you the output coming is as desired output, the thing left is to show now.